# How to consume a Chunked HTTP Stream with Apache Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I have an issue consuming a Chunked HTTP RSVP Stream using Camel.

The stream is [here](http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps) and you can find more information about it at the end of [this page](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/stream/2/rsvps/)

I have created a simple route such:

```
from("http4://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps").log(org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel.INFO, "MeetupElasticSearch.Log", "JSON RSVP ${body}")
```

But nothing happens no message are consumed. I tried by adding a camel timer before because I am not sure you can use http4 component directly in the `from` but result is the same.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the `http4` component in a `from()` directive.

However, there is several ways to call an URL and to retrieve the result:

One is to create a timer and call the `http4` component from a `to()` like this:

```
from("quartz2://HttpPoll/myTimer?trigger.repeatCount=0")
    .to("http4://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps")
    .log("Body is: ${body}")
    .to(mockDestination);
```

Another way is to use the [content enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) pattern if you want to for example aggegates results into one another stucture.

Note as well, if your URL is dynamic you must use [`recipientList()`](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) instead `to()`.

**UPDATE:**

Another way to consume a stream from the Internet is to use another component than `http4`: the [`camel-stream`](http://camel.apache.org/stream.html).

This one you can declare it in a `from()`directive:

```
 // Read stream from the given URL... an publish in a queue
    from("stream:url?url=http://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps&scanStream=true&retry=true").
      to("seda:processingQueue");

    // Read records from the processing queue
    // and do something with them.
    from("seda:processingQueue").to("log:out")
```

You can see more sample in [this site](http://henryk-konsek.blogspot.ch/2012/02/integration-by-examples-consuming.html).